# TableView not responsing to an "edit" button in UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

My application is a shopping list, with a UINavigationController pushing a UITableViewController. The navigation controller has an "Edit" button that handles deleting and rearranging the order of rows.

Everything is working perfectly so far. However I decided to include iAd in the application. I was able to do that in the UITableViewController, but the iAd scrolls with the TableView. So I followed [Ray Wenderlich's tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1371/how-to-integrate-iad-into-your-iphone-app) on how to include an iAd in a TableView, and his solution was to SubClass UIViewController and nest the TableView inside.

Now this method worked perfectly well except for one thing that I can't really get my head around. The tableView doesn't respond to the Edit button anymore. Tapping the edit does absolutely nothing! Can someone please explain why is this happening and what is the solution to it?

---

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure you need to handle the setEditing message yourself. You'll want to override `setEditing:animated:` in your view controller so it looks something like this.

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self.tableview setEditing:editing animated:animated];
}
```

If we could see the source code for `UITableViewController`, the implementation of this method would probably look something like this.